# What happens under the hood when URL's change in browser while loading

Tags: dns

When my browser loads *"wikipedia.com"* it will replace it by "*http://www.wikipedia.org*".

How does my browser know it has to change *".com"* in *".org"*? I assumed this was DNS related but I was not able to find any DNS record that provides a link from "*wikipedia.com*" to "*wikipedia.org*". This happens in all major browsers.

Can anyone explains what happens under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a simple server side [`301 permanent redirect`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2). There's a script on `wikipedia.com` which redirects all requests to `wikipedia.org` by sending the 301 status code:

[image]